# Addressing High Missingness in Data Analysis for Feature Selection Methods

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, missing-data, multiple-imputation

I'm working with a comprehensive dataset of 12,000 companies and 600 ESG metrics from Refinitiv, segmented into 10 sectors. In my feature selection process for determining influential ESG scores, I've encountered high missingness in top-ranked features (around 50%), identified using Shapley values and permutation importance. I initially used MissForest for imputation, followed by winsorization and scaling. My challenge is that methods like correlation and LASSO require fully imputed datasets. I considered multiple imputation via MICE, but faced issues with multicollinearity and the computational intensity of re-running models on each imputed dataset. I also wanted to retain as many variables as possible, making it difficult to remove variables due to multicollinearity. What alternative strategies can I use to address these issues in my paper, and how should the handling of missing values and multicollinearity be reported?